# Can't load Android Virtual Device

Tags: android

when I run my android application using eclipse 3.5 I receive an error called

"Android AVD Error.

No compatible target were found.Do you wish to add a new Android Virtual Device.
"

How can I load Android Virtual Device ?

Answer (score 3):

To add a new `AVD` in eclipse:

- Window => Android SDK and AVD manager
- New

Check what version you are using in your project and create a new AVD with that target version.

Comment: I had a similar problem, found out my AVD was for 2.3.1 but my project was 2.3.3.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found that I didn't have API 25 installed, and so I changed it from  'minSdkVersion 25' to 'minSdkVersion 19' and the error went away.

```
defaultConfig {

      ............

    minSdkVersion 19

    targetSdkVersion 26
```